# Finding the limit: $L = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \prod_{r=3}^{n} \frac{r^3 - 8}{r^3 + 8}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I'm trying to solve the following question. Have tried taking $\log$ on both sides, but didn't get very far. Seems difficult to apply L'Hopital's rule.

$L = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \prod_{r=3}^{n} \frac{r^3 - 8}{r^3 + 8}$

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha is giving me $\frac27$.

Comment: It factors and then telescopes nicely.

Comment: This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level. 1

Comment: For help on writing questions on this site, please see "How to ask a good question" at https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\prod_{r=3}^{n}\frac{r^3-8}{r^3+8}=\prod_{r=3}^{n}\frac{r-2}{r+2}\prod_{r=3}^{n}\frac{(r+1)^2+3}{(r-1)^2+3}=\frac{\prod_{k=1}^{n-2}k}{\prod_{k=5}^{n+2}k}\cdot\frac{\prod_{h=4}^{n+1}(h^2+3)}{\prod_{h=2}^{n-1}(h^2+3)}$$
for any $n\geq 7$ can be written as
$$ \frac{4!}{(n+2)(n+1)n(n-1)}\cdot\frac{((n+1)^2+3)(n^2+3)}{(2^2+3)(3^2+3)} $$
whose limit as $n\to +\infty$ is given by
$$ \frac{4!}{(2^2+3)(3^2+3)}=\frac{24}{7\cdot 12}=\color{red}{\frac{2}{7}}.$$

Comment: Looks someone disliked it, but anyway i like this elementary answer!